Azure Function app : Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (python)
Getting Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'
when running http-triggered azure function app (python 3.10)
The module is imported using from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
In order to force install of packages, I deployed the function using func azure functionapp publish fappname --build remote
The function runs succesfully in local environment. I have tried to develop it several times now without success.
Any ideas?
requirements.txt
aiofiles==23.2.1
aiohttp==3.9.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.2.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.30.1
azure-functions==1.18.0
azure-identity==1.15.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage==0.36.0
azure-storage-blob==12.13.0
azure-storage-file-datalake==12.5.0
azure-storage-queue==12.4.0
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==42.0.5
frozenlist==1.4.1
idna==3.6
isodate==0.6.1
msal==1.28.0
msal-extensions==1.1.0
multidict==6.0.5
numpy==1.26.4
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.2.1
portalocker==2.8.2
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.8.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.11.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1
yarl==1.9.4


Restarted the app and redeployed it using  func azure functionapp publish fappname --build remote
Also changed azure-storage-blob==12.13.0 to latest version


Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'

Based on the error you're encountering (ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'), it seems like there might be an issue with the package setup or the environment in your Azure Function app.
Make sure that the version of azure-storage-blob specified in your requirements.txt is compatible with the Azure Functions runtime. the azure-storage-blob version 12.13.0 should be fine, but you can try upgrading to the latest version available.

Check the import statement within the Azure Function code like below:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

dependency issues can arise due to conflicts or incomplete installations. Try to uninstall the environment and reinstalling dependencies by using below commands:


pip uninstall -r requirements.txt 
pip install -r requirements.txt


The Another approach is to deploy the function into portal by using visual studio code like below:


Then select the function which already created in portal and follow like below:

